# TOSCA - Jump to Module is not working, any solution to fix this?

Tags: tosca

If I right click on test step and select jump to module, it is not navigating to specific module.
Previously it was working.

Tried to remove and add module tab again but still it is not working.
Any solution for this?
I am using TOSCA 14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove existing workspace and add new workspace for same.